# Group and Merge array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am struggling around with the aggregation pipeline feature from MongoDB.
So far the output for one result looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "inbound",
  "sender": "postAG",
  "receiver": "maxMusterMan",
  "datetime": "20191125",
  "info": [
    {
      "q": "A",
      "value": "5",
      "name": null,
      "plz": 1234
    },
    {
      "q": "B",
      "value": "AS",
      "name": "ABS",
      "plz": null
    },
    {
      "q": "A",
      "value": "5",
      "name": "aa",
      "plz": null
    },
    ... more objects
  ]
}
```

The final result should look like:

```
{
  "type": "inbound",
  "sender": "postAG",
  "receiver": "maxMusterMan",
  "datetime": "20191125",
  "info": [
    {
      "q": "A",
      "value": "0",
      "name": "aa",
      "plz": 1234
    },
    {
      "q": "B",
      "value": "AS",
      "name": "ABS"
    }
  ]
}
```

So in a nutshell, I want to group the values from the array field info by the "q" field and merge the objects (newer one overwrites the old value).
Further I would like to remove all the values with value "" or null;
There are more fields in the real payload, so I would like to avoid to add a $cond for each field of the object.

Some approaches so far from my side:

- for the cleanup, use a UDF, but this is not possible in the pipeline.
  use map-reduce for the group and merge, not available in the pipeline.
- Please consider that the input file is the output from the several pipeline steps.
  So I can not just use map-reduce alone, first I need the pipeline too.

My idea was to create two views, first will do the pipeline stuff and second map-reduce, is this a good solution?

Thx
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really understand from your explanation if you can or cannot use map-reduce.

However assuming you can't and you have to 'concat' the pipelines there is no 'generic' workaround for multiple fields - you have to create a condition for each in the pipeline.

With that said here is a working pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$unwind" : "$info"
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$info.q",
                "type" : {
                    "$first" : "$type"
                },
                "sender" : {
                    "$first" : "$sender"
                },
                "receiver" : {
                    "$first" : "$receiver"
                },
                "datetime" : {
                    "$first" : "$datetime"
                },
                "values" : {
                    "$push" : "$info.value"
                },
                "names" : {
                    "$push" : "$info.name"
                },
                "plz" : {
                    "$push" : "$info.plz"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : 1.0,
                "type" : 1.0,
                "sender" : 1.0,
                "receiver" : 1.0,
                "datetime" : 1.0,
                "values" : {
                    "$filter" : {
                        "input" : "$values",
                        "as" : "curr",
                        "cond" : {
                            "$or" : [
                                {
                                    "$ne" : [
                                        "$$curr",
                                        null
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$ne" : [
                                        "$$curr",
                                        ""
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "names" : {
                    "$filter" : {
                        "input" : "$names",
                        "as" : "curr",
                        "cond" : {
                            "$or" : [
                                {
                                    "$ne" : [
                                        "$$curr",
                                        null
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$ne" : [
                                        "$$curr",
                                        ""
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "plz" : {
                    "$filter" : {
                        "input" : "$plz",
                        "as" : "curr",
                        "cond" : {
                            "$or" : [
                                {
                                    "$ne" : [
                                        "$$curr",
                                        null
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$ne" : [
                                        "$$curr",
                                        ""
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "sender" : 1.0,
                "receiver" : 1.0,
                "datetime" : 1.0,
                "type" : 1.0,
                "_id" : 1.0,
                "value" : {
                    "$cond" : {
                        "if" : {
                            "$gt" : [
                                {
                                    "$size" : "$values"
                                },
                                0.0
                            ]
                        },
                        "then" : {
                            "$arrayElemAt" : [
                                "$values",
                                -1.0
                            ]
                        },
                        "else" : null
                    }
                },
                "name" : {
                    "$cond" : {
                        "if" : {
                            "$gt" : [
                                {
                                    "$size" : "$names"
                                },
                                0.0
                            ]
                        },
                        "then" : {
                            "$arrayElemAt" : [
                                "$names",
                                -1.0
                            ]
                        },
                        "else" : null
                    }
                },
                "plz" : {
                    "$cond" : {
                        "if" : {
                            "$gt" : [
                                {
                                    "$size" : "$plz"
                                },
                                0.0
                            ]
                        },
                        "then" : {
                            "$arrayElemAt" : [
                                "$plz",
                                -1.0
                            ]
                        },
                        "else" : null
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$addFields" : {
                "infoArray" : [
                    {
                        "k" : "type",
                        "v" : "$_id"
                    },
                    {
                        "k" : "value",
                        "v" : "$value"
                    },
                    {
                        "k" : "name",
                        "v" : "$name"
                    },
                    {
                        "k" : "plz",
                        "v" : "$plz"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "$addFields" : {
                "info" : {
                    "$arrayToObject" : {
                        "$filter" : {
                            "input" : "$infoArray",
                            "as" : "curr",
                            "cond" : {
                                "$ne" : [
                                    "$$curr.v",
                                    null
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : null,
                "type" : {
                    "$first" : "$type"
                },
                "sender" : {
                    "$first" : "$sender"
                },
                "receiver" : {
                    "$first" : "$receiver"
                },
                "datetime" : {
                    "$first" : "$datetime"
                },
                "info" : {
                    "$push" : "$info"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```